# Avoid android gboard's "Tap to Google Search or more" popup in tests

Tags: android, adb, android-testing, gboard

At times in my android instrumented tests, I have this GBoard popup that appears: "**Tap to Google Search and more**".

Unfortunately, this happens randomly and this **makes my tests fail** because that popup seems to take focus.

How can I be sure that this popup will not display? Is there an `adb` command? Or something else that can be done?

[image: screenshot]